# Kohana redirect

Tags: redirect, kohana, routes

After a form-submit in Kohana, I want the user to go back to the homepage.
Is it correct to use a redirect for this?

```
public function action_edit($id)
{
    if (!empty($post))
    {
        if ($post->validate())
        {
            $this->request->redirect(Route::get('admin')->uri(array('action' => 'list')));

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `$this->request->uri($params)` (instead of `Route::get()->uri()`) maybe useful. For example, when you want to use current controller (redirect to another action) or the same route. It will use route params from current request by default.

Comment: Then don't you go to the exact same url, with $params?

Comment: The same *route*, but params may differ.

Answer (score 0):

The redirecting part is indeed correct.
The validation part is missing a few lines.

Comment: Thank you. The validation is indeed not complete, was just to make my point clear. Thanks!