# How to refresh / reload page in kohana? [post/prg]

Tags: php, redirect, http-post, refresh, kohana

I need to refresh registration page after form is successfully submitted, to prevent multiple submissons on page reload (cleaning $_POST/$_REQUEST).

Currently I'm using:

```
$this->redirect('news/create', 303);
```

I don't want to specify path everytime, which shortcut can I use?

**UPDATE:**

I made something like

```
$this->redirect("../" . $this->request->uri(), 303);
```

Thanks to [@biakaveron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5484838/5193609).But It's still messy, imho.

**Additional info:**

- [The PRG pattern](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)
- [Best Practices for Form Submit](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/2154/best-practices-for-form-submit/p1)

Comment: What is wrong with specyfing the path everytime? In most cases after submitting post you will be redirected do difrent url, I dont see anything wrong with specyfing url everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `$this->redirect($this->request->uri(), 303);` is the shortest way.